# UIButtons with icons don't like up

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode6, uistoryboard

One of my storyboard panes has a series of four UIButtons in it. Each button has some text and an Image assigned. They have been lined up so they are identical in size and X position.

However, the icons do not line up vertically, but are displayed directly next to the text.

I would prefer to have all he icons aligned vertically. I've looked through previous questions here, but surprisingly, I can't see this. Am I missing something painfully obvious here?

[image: the problem]

Aside from how to post an image, that is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is option for title, content and  images contentinsets in IB, select uibutton and explore it in IB

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ha, this was precisely what I was looking for! Perhaps Apple might LABEL IT NEXT TIME?!